# Iterating model that solves multiple routes with multiple locations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

I have multiple line feature classes that I would like to make routes and solve. For each of these routes I have specific start/stop points (feature classes) that will act as locations.

How could I build a model that would pull each route with its associated locations, solve, and write out the solved route?